# Create table of BBDD @variable

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a Table in a BBDD by variable in MYSQL. The problem i have is that the code doesn't work and I am not sure why.

```
$variable = "xxx_'".$_POST['idtour']."'_xxxx";

    // Create the table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tourname (
                    id_leg VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Identificación de la leg del tour, en orden')";         
    //The action
    mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Error ".mysqli_error());
```

I think is a problem with the "_".Any help will be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the `_`. It's the `'`. `"xxx_'".$_POST['idtour']."'_xxxx"` will result in `xxx_'value'_xxxx`, as a possible table name, and `'` is not valid in a table name. If you *MUST* include invalid characters, then you'll need to use the backtick operator.

```
$tablename = "`xxx_'".$var."'_xxxx`";
```

That should get you further towards your goal.

---

On a side note: creating a table based on a user-provided variable is a bad idea. It risks users being able to create some bizarre and destructive behavior, and very often it's better accomplished by adding a column to an existing table. Have you tried adding a column `user_idtour`?

Comment: Thanks cwallepoole, now works. This is the final code that i use:

    $tablename = "`ivao_".$nametour."_legs`";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tablename (
                        id_leg VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Identificación de la leg del tour, en orden')";
//Función para crear la tabla dentro de la BBDD 
        mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Error al crear la tabla en la base de datos ".mysqli_error());
And for your question, i don't want to add another file in the BBDD table. I want that the variable do this only.

Thanks again for all, Regards